# Netlify deploy building Babel warning

Tags: compiler-errors, babeljs, netlify

[babel error on netlify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wpeg.png)Whenever I push a deploy through netlify to my site, I shows me this babel error
[error of babel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oz2Xp.png)
so....
how do I resolve this?

I tried to search about it on many platforms like stack overflow, youtube and netlify but it was of no help

Comment: Rather than putting in links to screenshots, please copy and paste your errors into your question.  The code can be inserted inline or in code blocks - see [formatting on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for more information.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.